# Handsontable Select2 Dynamic Options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, handsontable

I am using handsontable with the select2 editor but I cannot seem to make dynamic options work with the dropdown menu, i.e. the options set at the the time of the handsontable initialisation are the only options that ever seem to show.

I have tried using a global variable as the source of the options and updating that at various points in my code and also using a function to return the same variable but neither attempt seems to work.

e.g.

```
var hot;
var data = [];

function customDropdownRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {

    if (instance.getCell(row, col)) {
        $(instance.getCell(row,col)).addClass('select2dropdown');
    }

    var selectedId;

    var colOptions = cellProperties.select2Options.data;

    if (colOptions != undefined) {

        for (var index = 0; index < colOptions.length; index++) {
            if (parseInt(value) === colOptions[index].id) {
                selectedId = colOptions[index].id;
                value = colOptions[index].text;            
            }
        }

        Handsontable.TextCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}

var  requiredText = /([^\s])/;

$(document).ready(function(){

    var
      $container = $("#example1"),
      $parent = $container.parent(),
      autosaveNotification;


    hot = new Handsontable($container[0], {
        columnSorting: true,
        stretchH: 'all',
        startRows: 8,
        startCols: 5,
        rowHeaders: true,
        colHeaders: ['Description', 'Cost', 'Remarks'],
        columns: [
            { data: 'description' },
            { 
                data: 'cost',
                editor: 'select2',
                renderer: customDropdownRenderer,
                select2Options: { data: getData(), dropdownAutoWidth: true }
            },
            { data: 'remarks' },
        ],
        minSpareCols: 0,
        minSpareRows: 1,
        contextMenu: true,
        data: []
    });

    data = [{id:'fixed',text:'Fixed'},{id:'variable',text:'Variable'}];
});

function getData() {
    return data;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zfmdu4wt/27/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined data multiple times and it is causing contention.

The following changes will fix it:

Define the following immediately after the .ready() function:

var source = [{id:'fixed',text:'Fixed'},{id:'variable',text:'Variable'}];

and update the select2Options to the following:

select2Options : { data: source, dropdownAutoWidth: true }

Comment: thanks @mpusarla, I've seen you answer on a few handsontable questions and they are a great help, I couldn't get this one to work though unless I've done something wrong - http://jsfiddle.net/zfmdu4wt/40/. I agree, `data` is a terrible variable name, I don't have it named that in my own code and in my own example the variable is being updated in a couple of different places because of ajax requests.

Comment: thanks, although a little strange that the table is showing the `id` of the selected option rather than the `text` attribute.

Comment: It is showing the text instead of id. Update the source to var source = [{id:1,text:'Fixed'},{id:2,text:'Variable'}]; and give it a try. In your example, the id and text are the same excepting for the case.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by re-using some code I had used to solve the same problem with the xeditable plugin.

Here's the updated code:

```
var hot;
var data = [];

function customDropdownRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {

  if (instance.getCell(row, col)) {
      $(instance.getCell(row,col)).addClass('select2dropdown');
  }

    var selectedId;

    var colOptions = cellProperties.select2Options.data;

    if (colOptions != undefined) {

        for (var index = 0; index < colOptions.length; index++) {
            if (parseInt(value) === colOptions[index].id) {
                selectedId = colOptions[index].id;
                value = colOptions[index].text;            
            }
        }

        Handsontable.TextCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}

var  requiredText = /([^\s])/;

$(document).ready(function(){

    var
      $container = $("#example1"),
      $parent = $container.parent(),
      autosaveNotification;


    hot = new Handsontable($container[0], {
        columnSorting: true,
        stretchH: 'all',
        startRows: 8,
        startCols: 5,
        rowHeaders: true,
        colHeaders: ['Description', 'Cost', 'Remarks'],
        columns: [
            { data: 'description' },
            { 
                data: 'cost',
                editor: 'select2',
                renderer: customDropdownRenderer,
                // select2Options: { data: getData(), dropdownAutoWidth: true }
                select2Options: { data: getSource(), dropdownAutoWidth: true, width: 'resolve', initSelection: getInitSel(false), query: getQuery }
            },
            { data: 'remarks' },
       ],
       minSpareCols: 0,
       minSpareRows: 1,
       contextMenu: true,
       data: []
    });

    data = [{id:'fixed',text:'Fixed'},{id:'variable',text:'Variable'}];
});

/*
function getData() {
    return data;
}
*/

// New Code

function getSource() {
    return data;
};

function getQuery(options) {
    options.callback({ results : getSource() });
};

function getInitSel(multiple) {
    return function(el, cb) {
        var t, toSet = [], sc = getSource();
        el[0].value.split(',').forEach(function(a) {

            for (var i = 0; i < sc.length; i++) {
                if (sc[i].id == Number(a.trim())) {
                    t = sc[i];
                }
            }

            // or, if you are using underscore.js
            // t = _.findWhere(sc, { id : Number(a.trim()) });

            if(t) toSet.push(t);
        });
        cb(multiple ? toSet : (toSet.length ? toSet[0] : null));
    };
};
```

and a fiddle for demonstration - http://jsfiddle.net/zfmdu4wt/38/